# Kotlin: How to insert a list of objects into Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to define common [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) methods in a base interface as shown here:

```
interface BaseDao<in I> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun create(obj: I)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun createAll(objects: List<I>)

    @Delete
    fun delete(obj: I)

}
```

The following `ProductDao` interface for [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) inherits from the base interface:

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao : BaseDao<Product> {

    // Specific methods

}
```

When I compile the definition for `fun createAll(objects: List<I>)` produces the following error:

> Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.

Comment: Is your Product table annotated with Entity annotation?

Comment: It’s what is written on the box - `I` needs to be annotated with `@Entity`

Comment: All other methods defined in the base class work. Only the `createAll()` method does not work.

Comment: No, the "I" doesn't need to be annotated, but if you do make BaseDao an abstract class with @Dao annotation it will work

Answer (score 12):

Try adding `@JvmSuppressWildcards` to your function.

```
@Insert
@JvmSuppressWildcards
fun createAll(objects: List<I>)
```

From the docs:

> Instructs compiler to generate or omit wildcards for type arguments corresponding to parameters with declaration-site variance, for example such as Collection has.
>
> It may be helpful only if declaration seems to be inconvenient to use from Java.

Answer (score 10):

I've resolved issue by:

```
@Dao
interface BaseDao<T> {

    /**
     * Insert a list in the database. If the item already exists, replace it.
     *
     * @param list the items to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @JvmSuppressWildcards
    abstract fun insertAll(list: List<T>)

}
```

**@JvmSuppressWildcards**  done the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I believe I found the solution:

It is impossible for Kotlin to create Array of generic objects so you have to make such a workaround:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun create(obj: I)

@Transaction
fun createAll(objects: List<I>) = objects.forEach {insert(it)}
```

`@Transaction` should make it all happen in a single transaction so it should not introduce any performance issues, but I am not certain of this.

What is more, a simple:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun createAll(objects: List<Product>)
```

will work as well, as long as it is using real objects, not generics.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Entity` annotation for your model class (you should have concrete model class for Dao methods),
but you use generics in your interface `BaseDao<in I>`.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data.html

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to implement the `BaseDao` interface in **Java** until the issue persists.

```
public interface IBaseDao<T> {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @WorkerThread
    void save(T item);

    @Delete
    @WorkerThread
    void delete(T item);

    @Delete
    @WorkerThread
    void deleteAll(List<T> items);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    @WorkerThread
    void saveAll(List<T> items);
}
```

Abstract `BaseDao` in Kotlin

```
abstract class BaseDao<T> : IBaseDao<T> {

    @WorkerThread
    open fun getAll(): List<T> = TODO("Override and place the annotation @Query. Ex: @Query(\"SELECT * FROM Model\")")

    @WorkerThread
    open fun loadAll(): LiveData<List<T>> = TODO("Override and place the annotation @Query. Ex: @Query(\"SELECT * FROM Model\")")
}
```

It works!